# Conversão explicita com "static_cast" não ocorre

Tags: c++

De acordo com o *C++ Como Programar, 8ª ed.*, durante a operação de dois números (ex.: 10/3) a parte fraccionária do ressultado é perdida antes de ser armazenado na variavél .
Para que isto seja evitado, podemos recorrer à conversão explicita usando o operador *static_cast*. Então eu escrevi assim o código:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  double flutuante;
  int tres = 3;
  int dez = 10;

  flutuante = static_cast<double> (dez / tres);

  std::cout <<" resultdo: " << flutuante;
}
```

esperando como resultao: 3,333... mas o resulado que obtenho é simplesmente o 3.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o operador `/` quando aplicado a dois inteiros produz como um resultado um inteiro. Para que a operação devolva um `float` deves fazer cast de um dos argumentos para `float`.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    double flutuante;
    int tres = 3;
    int dez = 10;

    flutuante = dez / static_cast<double> (tres);

    std::cout <<" resultdo: " << flutuante;

    return 0;
}
```